# Using Free Distort on text in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, perspective, isometric, cc-2015

Why does this not seem to work, and does anybody else know a way to get type distorted?
Specifically I have an isometric building and I would like to put the names of the surrounding streets "on the ground" so to speak.

Comment: Using free distort works on live type no problem for me.

Comment: Can you specify what exactly didn't work? What have you tried?

Comment: I used the type tool to create text, then selected the free distort tool. Dragging the corners showed an outline of how the shape should distort, but when letting go of the mouse it just snaps back to its original shape. The other tools in the free transform menu work on the text, but not free distort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the text, then go to Effect->3D->Rotate.
Then choose the *Isometric Top* option:

[image]

For an alternative orientation you can change the parameters like so:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. Can't believe I forgot it existed